# Unable to save config to file, multiple times

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationmanager

I have code, including unit tests, that tries to save the config file multiple times.  When I try to save the config file a second time I get this error:

> Unable to save config to file [FileName]

My code is basically doing this:

```
{
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configName);
...change some values...
config.save();
}
```

and then again later

```
{
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configName);
...change some values in a different way...
config.save();
}
```

When I execute the config.save for the second time, there is a 10 second delay, and then I get the error.  Does anyone know how to 'unlock' this file?

---

I tried keeping the instance of the config variable, i.e. 'in-scope' but that did not work.

```
private static Configuration GetConfiguration(string configName)
        {
            Configuration retval;
            if (_configs == null) _configs = new Dictionary<string, Configuration>();
            if (_configs.TryGetValue(configName, out retval)) return retval;
            retval = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configName);
            _configs.Add(configName, retval);
            return retval;
        }
```

and then

```
{
Configuration config = GetConfiguration(configName);
...change some values...
config.save();
}
```

along with

```
{
Configuration config = GetConfiguration(configName);
...change some values in a different way...
config.save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ug.  I was causing the problem elsewhere in my code.

I had a function like this:

```
    private bool FileHasString(string filename, string searchString)
    {
        string content = (new StreamReader(filename)).ReadToEnd();
        return content.IndexOf(searchString) > 0;
    }
```

I assumed that when the stream reader left scope, that the lock on the file ended.  The lock apparently did not, and that what was causing the trouble.

This works much better.

```
    private bool FileHasString(string filename, string searchString)
    {
        var sr = new StreamReader(filename);
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        return content.IndexOf(searchString) > 0;
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep; working with the file as a file will trip up ConfigurationManager's best efforts at concurrency. The only refactor I'd suggest is using the `using` block construct: `using(var sr = new StreamReader(filename)){ string content = ... }`. This assures the StreamReader, and its file handle, are disposed even if an exception is thrown, and provides a consistent, clean way of working with IDisposable objects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you keep `config` in scope between these two code blocks, so you don't have to load it a second time?

The logic behind ConfigurationManager and the System.Configuration namespace is actually quite complex, because the configuration it produces isn't from just one file, even when you are specifically asking for the EXE config. It's possible, for instance, for the user.config to be corrupted, which prevents loading the entire EXE config. I've seen that happen more times than I can count, and the best fix I know of is just to blow away the user config and start over. Similarly, it's possible that the user.config is locked because ConfigurationManager itself is doing something to it.

Comment: I tried that.  Maybe I did it the wrong way.  Here is what I did.